Time resolution x axis
I would like to format my data with 30-minute intervals on the x-axis instead of the date. However, I seem to be doing something wrong. Also when I am trying to use facet_grid again on the x-axis the time is not visible. Any suggestion? The data was collected during 4 days
library(readr)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)


data<- read_csv("Energy readings - 25th May to 22nd June - Group 1 .csv")
data<-as.data.frame(data)

data<- read_csv("Energy readings - 25th May to 22nd June - Group 1 .csv")
data<-as.data.frame(data)

data <- data %>%
  mutate(start_time = as.POSIXct(start_time, format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", tz = "UTC"))

# Create the plot
ggplot(data, aes(x = start_time, y = deviceId, fill = energy_use_wh)) +
  geom_tile() +
  scale_fill_gradient(low = "white", high = "blue") +
  labs(title = "Energy Use Over Time",
       x = "Start Time",
       y = "Device ID",
       fill = "Energy Use (Wh)") +
  scale_x_datetime(date_breaks = "30 minutes", date_labels = "%H:%M") +
  theme_minimal()


Data

structure(list(deviceId = c("dev_0CDC7E3E85E8", "dev_0CDC7E3E85E8", 
"dev_0CDC7E3E85E8", "dev_0CDC7E3E85E8", "dev_0CDC7E3E85E8", "dev_0CDC7E3E85E8", 
"dev_0CDC7E3E85E8", "dev_0CDC7E3E85E8", "dev_0CDC7E3E85E8", "dev_0CDC7E3E85E8"
), channel_id = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), start_time = c("2023-05-25 12:00:00.000 +0100", 
"2023-05-25 12:30:00.000 +0100", "2023-05-25 13:30:00.000 +0100", 
"2023-05-25 14:00:00.000 +0100", "2023-05-25 14:30:00.000 +0100", 
"2023-05-25 15:00:00.000 +0100", "2023-05-25 15:30:00.000 +0100", 
"2023-05-25 16:00:00.000 +0100", "2023-05-25 16:30:00.000 +0100", 
"2023-05-25 17:30:00.000 +0100"), energy_use_wh = c(0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))


You need to convert your start_time column from character class to a datetime class. lubridate::ymd_hms() should work easily.

You need to use date_breaks = "30 min" instead of date_breaks = "30 minutes", but otherwise the code seems to run okay with the data you posted. Breaks every 30 minutes for 4 days will give you 192 breaks though, which is a lot to actually display..
